# In Google Content Experiments, why are bounces greater than number of experiment sessions?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, content-experiments

I've recently begun conducting content experiments on my website. I'm running a basic A/B, comparing an original template with a new template for certain page types. For some of the experiments, there are more total bounces being recorded than experiment sessions.

For example, see this screencast: http://screencast.com/t/fLhVN88w81U

You can see in the table that bounces are higher than sessions, and therefore a bounce rate is being reported of higher than 100%. The line graph above the table is also telling. I've run several other experiments, and this is not a widespread occurrence. It only appears to happen when the total number of experiment sessions is less than 2,500. Is this just a figment of small sample sizes?

Thanks!